# submit button not working after loading a php form using jquery load

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this website which is under construction. 
http://www.orangewebscape.com/

The problem is in the packages page. When you click on the packages menu item a jquery load loads a php file named wrap2.php . The wrap2 page has a big form with many checkboxes , 3 textboxes and a submit button. The submit button works well in chrome but fails to work in every other available browser(IE9,opera,mozilla). Though it works in IE8. Even the css style don't apply to the form and the submit button.

**Jquery load**

```
    $('#tabs li').click(function(){
     $("#loading").show();

     $('#container').load('views/'+$(this).attr("class")+'.php', function(){  

setTimeout( "jQuery('#dloading').hide();",2000 );
     });
        return false;
    });
```

**wrap2.php**

```
<div id="wrap2" >


&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

<h1>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span id="packtop">Build Your Order</span></h1><br><br>
<div id="buildtext"> We have choices and options for everybody. Please pick as many you like and   submit a query. We assure you of an instant reply.</div>
<div class="servcont">
<form name="packages" action="core/orderplace.php" method="POST"       onsubmit="xmlhttpPost3('core/orderplace.php', 'packages', 'MyResult4', '<img src=\'pleasewait.gif\'>'); return false;">
<br>
<div class="plancont">
<div id="plantit">Biz Launch Pack</div> 

<div id="planbody">
<ul>
<li><img src="styles/images/2.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> Web Presence Pack <span id="price">INR 6717*</span></li>

<hr>
<li>Responsive Website Dev<span id="price"> 2499</span></li>
<li>Web Hosting <span id="price"> 2499</span></li>
<li>Email id's (pro+) <span id="price"> 1320</span></li>
<li>Domain name <span id="price"> 398</span></li>
<li>Customised Blog <span id="price"> Free</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<br>
<li><img src="styles/images/2.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> Print & Design Pack <span id="price">INR 1196*</span></li>

<hr>
<li>Logo Design<span id="price"> 298</span></li>
<li>Business card <span id="price"> 198</span></li>
<li>Brochure design<span id="price"> 498</span></li>
<li>Tshirt Design<span id="price"> 198</span></li>

</ul><br>
<ul>
<li><img src="styles/images/2.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> Stationary design Pack <span id="price">INR 896*</span></li>

<hr>
<li>Letter Head<span id="price"> 198</span></li>
<li>Envelope Deisgn<span id="price"> 198</span></li>
<li>Folder design<span id="price"> 298</span></li>
<li>CD Cover design<span id="price"> 198</span></li>

</ul>
<div id="totprice">Total = INR <span id="str">8800</span>*</div>
</div>

<div id="finalpricefoot">Offer Price - <b>INR 7800</b>* </div>
<div id="cartbt"><br><br><br> <input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Business Pack" /> Select This Package</div>
</div>






<div class="plancont"> 
<div id="plantit">Bands ,Events  & Gigs</div> 

<div id="planbody">
<ul>
<li><img src="styles/images/2.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> Web Presence Pack <span id="price">INR 5397*</span></li>

<hr>
<li>Responsive Website Dev<span id="price"> 2499</span></li>
<li>Web Hosting <span id="price"> 2499</span></li>
<li>Domain name <span id="price"> 398</span></li>
<li>Customised Blog <span id="price"> Free</span></li>
<br>
</ul>
<ul>
<br>
<li><img src="styles/images/2.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> Print & Design Pack <span id="price">INR 1393*</span></li>

<hr>
<li>Logo Design<span id="price"> 298</span></li>
<li>Flyer Design <span id="price"> 199</span></li>
<li>Poster design<span id="price"> 499</span></li>
<li>Banner Design<span id="price"> 199</span></li>
<li>Tshirt Design<span id="price"> 198</span></li>


</ul><br>
<ul>
<li><img src="styles/images/2.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> Creative Pack <span id="price">99*</span></li>

<hr>
<li>Mascot Design<span id="price"> Variable</span></li>

<li>FB timeline cover<span id="price"> 99</span></li>

</ul><br>



<div id="totprice">Total = INR <span id="str">6889</span>*</div>
</div>

<div id="finalpricefoot">Offer Price - <b>INR 5889</b>* </div>
<div id="cartbt"><br><br><br><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Band,Events,Gigs,Package" /> Select This Package</div>
</div>
<div class="plancont"><div id="plantit">Individuals / Professionals</div> 

<div id="planbody">
<ul>
<li><img src="styles/images/2.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> Web Presence Pack <span id="price">INR 5397*</span></li>

<hr>
<li>Responsive Website Dev<span id="price"> 2499</span></li>
<li>Web Hosting <span id="price"> 2499</span></li>
<li>Domain name <span id="price"> 399</span></li>
<li>Customised Blog <span id="price"> Free</span></li>
<br>
</ul>
<ul>
<br>
<li><img src="styles/images/2.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> Print & Design Pack <span id="price">INR 497*</span></li>

<hr>
<li>Logo Design<span id="price"> 298</span></li>
<li>Business card <span id="price"> 199</span></li>
<li>Book Cover Design<span id="price"> Variable</span></li>
<br>
</ul><br>
<ul>
<li><img src="styles/images/2.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> Stationary design Pack <span id="price">INR 896*</span></li>

<hr>
<li>Letter Head<span id="price"> 198</span></li>
<li>Envelope Deisgn<span id="price"> 198</span></li>
<li>Folder design<span id="price"> 298</span></li>
<li>CD Cover design<span id="price"> 198</span></li>

</ul>
<div id="totprice">Total = INR <span id="str">6790</span>*</div>
</div>

<div id="finalpricefoot">Offer Price - <b>INR 5790</b>* </div>
<div id="cartbt"><br><br><br><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Individual & Professionals"> Select This Package</div>


</div>







<br><br><br><br>



</div><br><br>
<h1><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspIndividual Picks</h1><br>
<div id="itemcont">


<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext"> Web Presence Pack</div>
<div id="indibody">Website + Email+ Hosting + Domain+Blog <br><br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Webpack subscription">INR 6717*</div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext"> Website Development</div>
<div id="indibody">Responsive Website + CSS3 + amazing stuff<br><br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Website development">INR 2499*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext"> Business Card Design</div>
<div id="indibody">High Quality & Innovative cards. 1 or 2 Sided<br><br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="business card Designing">INR 198*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">Logo Designing</div>
<div id="indibody">Highly creative logo designing<br><br><br>      
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Logo Designing">INR 298*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext"> Brochure Designing</div>
<div id="indibody">Various Types of Brochures. 2,3 <br>& 4 fold.<br><br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Brochure Designing">INR 498*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">T-shirt Designing</div>
<div id="indibody">Simplistic or innovative designs<br><br>   <br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="T-shirt Designing">INR 198*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">Flyer Designing</div>
<div id="indibody">Flyers for parties, events, gigs & shows. HQ<br><br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Flyer Designing">INR 199*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">Poster Designing</div>
<div id="indibody">Poster for anything.<br><br>   <br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Poster Designing">INR 499*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext"> Banner Designing</div>
<div id="indibody">Simplistic or High Quality Banner designing.<br><br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Banner Designing">INR 399*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">Letter Head</div>
<div id="indibody">Part of Corporate Branding<br><br>   <br> 
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="letter Head Designing">INR 199*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">Envelope Design</div>
<div id="indibody">Creative and Awe-inspiring designs<br><br>   <br> 
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Envelope Designing">INR 199*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">Folder Design</div>
<div id="indibody">Simple and eye catching deisgns for folders.<br><br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Folder Design">INR 299*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">CD Cover Design</div>
<div id="indibody">CD covers.<br><br>   <br> 
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="CDcover Designing">INR 199*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">App Icon & Buttons Design</div>
<div id="indibody">Icons & Buttons for websites & Apps<br><br>   
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Application Icon Designing">INR 199*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">Books Cover Design</div>
<div id="indibody">Book covers.<br><br>   <br> 
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Book Cover Designing">INR 499*</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="indiitem">
<div id="inditext">Mascot Designing</div>
<div id="indibody">Highly Creative Thinking<br><br><br> 
<div id="indiprice"><input type="checkbox" name="pack[]" value="Mascot Designing">Variable</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



<div id="formel">Name *</div>
<div id="formel"><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="20" ></div>
<div id="formel">Email * </div>
<div id="formel"><input type="text" name="fmail" id="fmail" size="20" ></div><br><br>
<div id="formel">Phone No </div>
<div id="formel"><input type="text" name="phone2" id="phone2" size="20" ></div>
<div id="formel">Country *</div>
<div id="formel"><input type="text" name="country" id="country" size="20" ></div>

<input type="submit" id="formsent" value="Order" name="forpackages" />
<div id="MyResult4" ></div>

</form>
<br>



</div>
```

Comment: Do you have function `xmlhttpPost3` ?

Comment: ya ! it's in a seperate .js ! The question here is when i click the submit button nothing works. But in chrome everything works

Comment: worst code i'he ever seen. `id` used like `class`, `settimeout` instead of `.delay()`.. and `.php` files with only `html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Looks like the HTML-tags are unbalanced. There appears to be an extra `</div>` just before the **Individual Picks**-section. Different browsers will try to recover from errors like that differently. In this case the extra closing tag is probably causing the `<form>` to end on the `</div>` on the line before **Name ***, i.e. before the button is parsed, so the button isn't connected to any forms.</strike>

Comment: let me check in again ! But if i try to open the php form directly through browser instead of jquery load the submit button works.

Comment: @stasGrin it's my first attempt in web development. i have to learn a lot.

Comment: @SaurabhShukla Actually looking at it again it appears to be correct, sorry. It's just missing a closing a tag at the end, which threw me off. But in order to debug you could try to reduce the code, delete everything inside the form except the button and a single field, and see if that works.

Comment: How should i group the checkboxes with the div ?

Comment: Problem sorted out. Changed a few div's and voila ! Thanks for the help.